# netbeans dependant libs do not compile after change

Tags: java, netbeans, dependencies, build-process

Using NetBeans 7.3 and writing Java code.
I've got a Web Server Project that is dependent on a lib (both are my code).
I've added the lib to the Server dependencies list by following the path: project properties -> libraries (add jar/folder).

If I change the code in the lib and "clean and build" the web server - the lib doesn't recompile (although NetBeans recognizes the change and alerts me with hint on problems).

I've tried with and without "compile on save" in both projects.
I am almost sure this used to work and am guessing that I probably changed something in the project to make the dependent lib not compile.

Any ideas what to look for? which parameter controls this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems all I needed to do was to add my libs as Project (project properties, Libraries, Add Project)and not as jar files...

that fixed all the dependencies issues...